# Is it necessary to use the keyword 'var' to declare a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, keyword

I have found that it does not seem necessary to use the keyword 'var' when declaring a variable in Javascript.  In fact, I have found no bad side effects from omitting it altogether.

Perhaps this is bad form, but can someone explain why it would be necessary?

Comment: It is necessary and you definitely should declare variables (at some appropriate scope) with `var`. In "strict" mode, failure to declare a variable is a runtime error.

Comment: Polluting the global scope at random is Very Bad.

Comment: http://blog.safeshepherd.com/23/how-one-missing-var-ruined-our-launch/

Comment: @Andy -- That was a fun read, nice article!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the keyword `var` ensures that your variable is properly scoped.  If you do not use the keyword, then JavaScript will automatically create the variable as a global scope, which can cause issues later in the execution of your page.

```
name = 'Bic'; // implicitly global

function myFunc() {
    var name = 'John'; // this variable is scoped here
    console.log(name); // John
    getName(); // Bic
}

function getName() {
    console.log(name); //Bic
}

myFunc();
getName();
```

In the code above, I declared a global name, and a scoped name. Note, the global name lingers on after myFunc() has finished executing. `name` is a property of most HTML elements. In this particular answer, my declaration of name without the `var` keyword can have detrimental affects to a page's execution. The value of `name` gets thrown out of scope, and this can affect targeting elements, and other things. If you take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wRj4y/), and click Run again after it loads, you will notice it automatically opens a new tab. This is because the original value of name has been clobbered, and the page does not know where to truly open.

As a general rule, it is good to always declare variables with the `var` keyword, as this makes it easier to follow the scope of that variable, as avoids unforeseen issues they can cause.

As was noted by Pointy, the 'use strict' pragma (introduced in ECMAScript 5) actually prohibits the declaration of variables without the `var` keyword.

Comment: And in "strict" mode, undeclared variables result in an error.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't declare it, perhaps you are accessing a global var. be careful with that because you can get undesired side effects.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, declaring a variable **requires** the *var* keyword. There are other ways of creating variables though, such as including them in a formal parameter list:

```
function foo(a, b, c) {...}
```

here *a*, *b*, and *c* are created more or less as if they were declared with *var*. The ill effects of creating variables without *var* are noted in other answers.